# Nautilus crashes seconds after launching

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

This problem developed after I updated Ubuntu. 
I have tried purging and reinstalling nautilus but the problem persists.

This is the output from terminal when I run it:

```
(nautilus:12554): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: <broken file>:1:0: Failed to import: The resource at '/org/gnome/libgd/tagged-entry/default.css' does not exist

(nautilus:12554): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/ozuf/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
**
ERROR:nautilus-canvas-container.c:6021:finish_adding_new_icons: assertion failed: (!container->details->auto_layout)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Please do you have any idea what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: @M.Becerra it saya `bash: cd: /home/ozuf/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: Not a directory`

Comment: My bad, made a mistake. This one is correct `ls -l /home/ozuf/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home`

Comment: `-rw------- 1 root root 29508 Oct 22 22:21 /home/ozuf/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read from the error message:

`/home/ozuf/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied`

And confirmed by:

```
ls -l /home/ozuf/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home

-rw------- 1 root root 29508 Oct 22 22:21 /home/ozuf/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home
```

The file needed by Nautilus is owned by root, so you would need to run Nautilus with `sudo`, which you shouldn't.

**To change the ownership back to your user**

You can simply get the ownership of the whole directory, as it's likely some more files will be owned by root and could cause trouble in the future.

```
cd ~/.local/share 

sudo chown $USER -R ./gvfs-metadata
```

That fixes the permission problem. To fix the second problem which is

```
ERROR:nautilus-canvas-container.c:6021:finish_adding_new_icons: assertion failed: (!container->details->auto_layout`:
```

1. From home, run `cd .config` and `rm -rf nautilus`
2. Also from home run `.local/share` and `rm -rf nautilus`.